# Script on reboot

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

So, I programmed a simple script to alert on slack whenever the server is rebooted.
What I did:
In /etc/rc6.d/R99reboot-slack: (I tried with R01reboot-slack)

```
#!/bin/sh
/scr/msg.sh "Server restarting...."
```

and in /scr/msg.sh I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
MSG=$1
API="API_TOKEN_HERE"
USERNAME="USERNAME HERE"
IMAGE="SOME IMAGE HERE"
CHANNEL="SOME CHANNEL HERE"
slackcli -t $API -h $CHANNEL -m "$MSG" -u $USERNAME -i $IMAGE
```

Using the slack-cli from https://github.com/candrholdings/slack-cli

The problem:

When I reboot, the script doesn't run at all, I tried with a:

```
echo "Hey, I did run!" > /scr/info.txt
```

But it returns nothing.

Both executables have shebangs and executable permissions. (I tried giving them 777 but it didn't work). I also tried changing from /bin/sh to /bin/bash, changing the user, putting sudo... But nothing works...

Running both scripts directly, **does work.**

This is on Ubuntu Server 16.04.
As requested, the output of:

```
ls -l /scr/msg.sh /etc/rc6.d/K99reboot-slack

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 119 Jun 18 19:02 /etc/rc6.d/K99reboot-slack
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 207 Jun 18 18:58 /scr/msg.sh
```

Comment: Are you running this as a user? User's don't have permission to access `/root` (the root home folder). Put your script somewhere else.

Comment: Since I run reboot from root, shouldn't the script run on root too?

Comment: Apparently not. Add a `whoami` or `id` to the script.

Comment: I moved the script to a /scr/ folder accessible to all users, the same Permission Denied...

Comment: Why are you even running this script at root?  Just put it in a user's (even root's, if you insist on running scripts as root) cron table with a schedule of `@reboot`.  Also, the script as written is a `bash` script, so you might want to invoke it with `bash` rather than `sh`.

Comment: 1) If the script is in `/etc/rc0.d/` it will be run by root. The `sudo sh` is not needed. 2) Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `ls -l /root/scripts/slack/msg.sh /etc/rc0.d/R99reboot-slack` just in case. 3) This isn't the error you are getting but will probably be the next one once this one is solved: make sure that `slackcli` is in root's `$PATH` or use the full path to it in your script.

Comment: @terdon updated as requested.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I want it to run *before* reboot, not after.

Comment: Rebooting is runlevel 6; not runlevel 0.  `rc0.d` is run at _shutdown_.  `rc6.d` is run at reboot.

Comment: @DopeGhoti you're quite right, of course, but something is attempting (and failing) to run the script. Otherwise the OP wouldn't be seeing the error.

Comment: @terdon there was another script on /etc/rc6.d with similar content, changed now.

Comment: Add `set -x` to the script and pipe its output (stdout and stderr) to a log that can be reviewed; you can then see exactly what command is being executed to generate the error.

Comment: What a mess! Now the script is on rc6.d and there's nothing else.

Comment: I would also try moving the script from `/root` to `/bin` or some other standard location. The error you see can be because the user attempting to run the script doesn't have execute permissions either for the script or for one of the directories in the script's path. This should be done by root, so I don't really see how that's possible but try moving it, just in case. And definitely try `set -x` as @DopeGhoti suggested.

Comment: After a lot of cleanup, and removing other scripts that may be giving the error. I changed the script path to /scr/, running the K99 script manually does work, but on reboot, nothing is shown (not even on the console).

Comment: It seems that the Permission Denied was being caused by another script.

Comment: Is it possible, that the script isn't having enough time to make the request to slack API?

Comment: As a test, I added a echo "something" > file.txt to the script, to test if it was being ran. It isn't.

Comment: @terdon I already did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't guaranteed to work, but try creating a cron job using

```
crontab -e
```

then in the file, put

```
@reboot /scr/msg.sh "Server restarting...."
```

and it should run on reboot. 

 Disclaimer: I have never personally tried this, and your success may vary.